# URL Rewrite/Mod Rewrite .htaccess on Apache and spring mvc

Tags: spring, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a single point of entry on my website

example.com/AAA/BBB

All access to the DB/application is through this spring mvc controller.

I would like to show my URL from what is shown above to.

example.com/AAA-BBB

The idea is to remove /AAA/BBB, to give meaningful sentence like AAA-BBB

I am using apache2 on Ubuntu and Spring mvc

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: First verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Yes, its enabled, its rewriting like example, RewriteRule ^(.*)/Cochin/(.*)$  $1/kochi/$2 [R=301,L]
                RewriteRule ^(.*)/cochin/(.*)$  $1/kochi/$2 [R=301,L]

Comment: Keep above rule below your 301/302 rules. And also tell me what exact URL are you entering in browser?

Comment: entering http://example.com/halls/chennai, it has a spring mvc controller to fetch data from DB, want to stay url like http://example.com/mantapams-in-chennai on the url browser, functionality like first one

Comment: There are 2 problems. You have 2 hyphens and you don't have `halls` in pretty URL. If you enter  `example.com/halls-chennai` then it will be routed to `example.com/halls/chennai`.